# How long does a recorded WebEx session remain available online?

Tags: screen-capture, webex

How long does a recorded WebEx session remain available online?
I'd like to make a demo available around my company for a couple of months.
I have the link to the recorded session - should I just email this round, or should I rehost the downloaded version myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network-Based Recordings do not automatically delete. Recordings will remain active as long as they are available on your WebEx site and your WebEx site is active.